# WebAudio changing of orientation of Listener and/or Panner

Tags: three.js, web-audio-api

I am trying to understand how the WebAudio API would work. I have two objects; one representing the listener and one the source. And have used the below link as an example. I am able to move the source and the sound position changes.

https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/panner-node/

The command to change the orientation has been provided: viz `this.panner.setOrientation` or `this.listener.setOrientation`. The question I have is: if I have a source or listener object (in canvas mode using ThreeJS viz. we know its position and rotation) how do I change the orientation of either the panner or listener (as the case may be) via JS.

An example would greatly help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use THREE's PositionalAudio object?  https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/audio/PositionalAudio.  That lets you add a sound to mesh object, and THREE will take care of moving it.  If you want to source a different sound than an AudioBuffer, just connect the audio source to the .gain of the PositionalAudio object.

Comment: I noticed that there was an echo that crept in while using positional audio .. which I did not notice in the raw code

Comment: hmm, interesting.  Got a sample?  I can hit up the THREE folks.

Comment: perhaps I can share the whole use-case. This is like a peer-to-peer audio meeting, where users are speaking to one another using their microphones. The users themselves are placed across a canvas space (a la camera, as we usually do). Using WebRTC P2P, I am creating multiple input streams for each user. What I realised when I first attempted to use ThreeJS positional audio, was that even if there were no others in the "room" there was an echo. When I wrote my own getMediaStream I did not push the stream to the user's own speaker. That helped. What remains is positional audio