# ThreeJS Positional Audio with WebRTC streams produces no sound

Tags: three.js

I am trying to use ThreeJS positional audio with WebRTC to build a sort of 3D Room audio chat feature. I am able to get the audio streams sent across the clients. However, the positional audio does not seem to work. Irrespective of where the user (camera) moves, the intensity of the audio remains the same. Some relevant code is being posted below:

The getUserMedia has the following in the promise response

```
// create the listener
listener = new THREE.AudioListener();

 // add it to the camera object
camera.object3D.add( listener );

 //store the local stream to be sent to other peers
 localStream = stream;
```

Then on each WebRTC PEER connection, I set the stream that is received to a mesh using Positional Audio

```
// create the sound object
sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio( listener ); // using the listener created earlier
const soundSource = this.sound.context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

// set the media source to as the sound source
sound.setNodeSource(soundSource);

// assume that I have handle to the obj where I need to set the sound
   obj.object3D.add( sound )
```

This is done for each of the clients and these local streams are being sent via WebRTC to one another, however there is no sound from the speakers? Thanks

Comment: Have you added the positional audio object to the scene graph?

Comment: hmm. you mean something like `camera.object3D.add( sound)` if I need the sound also to be attached to the camera ... because in my use-case the sound is the voice of the user and the listener the ears of the user. ok, will give it a try. Thanks @Mugen87

Comment: The above makes no difference. My view was: for the current user, I just need to store the stream (say, mystream) so that it can be sent to the other peers via webRTC. And for each of the others when I receive their stream (via `onAddSteam event`) I create `<audio>` objects in DOM and set the srcObj to the stream. I thought that would ensure that the steam from each peer is already "positioned". Obviously, that thinking seem wrong

Comment: Positional means spatial sound. Just adding an audio element in the DOM does not ensure 3D sound. Check out this demo to see the intended usage of `PositionalAudio`: https://threejs.org/examples/webaudio_timing.html

Comment: Got it. For my use-case, I need to add the peer stream to the objects (other players) that are being created, so that when they move, automatically, the panner values will change. Will give it a try. Thanks @Mugen87

Comment: Hello @Mugen87, I studied the link you posted and followed it in a similar manner except in the example it is a local sound file that is being played, in my case it is an audio stream that is coming from another client. I have edited the question to reflect the current code, yet there is no output. Thanks

Comment: Any chances you can demonstrate the problem in a reduced test case? A [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/) makes it easier to debug the issue.

Comment: hmm. let me try since it involves WebRTC with ice-servers et al. Also, the canvas is being created using the WebVR framework a-frame. I will see how best I can create a test case. Thanks

Comment: If the problem is audio related, it should be sufficient to create a stream via `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` like in this example: https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/stream-source-buffer/. This small app actually works on my laptop.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. I think I may not have mentioned that I got the whole webrtc audio working using Audio Context and sending streams to one another. In that version, on receipt of the audio stream from peers I was adding an `<audio>` element in the DOM. Works and is live. The challenge came when I wanted to make it positional. That is when I moved to using ThreeJS PositionalAudio in place of what the demo shows. And am having problems there.

Comment: This was an earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754669/webaudio-changing-of-orientation-of-listener-and-or-panner I posted on the same.

Comment: Okay, I see. In any event, a test case will hopefully help to make progress in this issue.

Comment: Agree. Just not sure how to get all the code in a single page with JS. Meanwhile, the only way this seems to work (tested locally) is where the microphone input streams needs to added to the canvas via an PositionalAudio sound object. But that causes the screeching sound. My thought being that the user need not move her/his stream to the speaker and only the received audio streams need to be moved to the speaker. Hence have been trying onto to create PositonalAudio on the receiving streams.

Comment: If there are three users A, B and C. In users A browser, only streams of B and C need to be Positional Audio sources (and vice versa). Is that an invalid thought?

Comment: To give an update: the only way I am able to hear the audio streams (positional) is to create an audio object in memory. Thus for every stream, besides adding the source to the entity in the canvas, I need to add a `var audio = new Audio()` and set the source `audio.srcObject = source`. Then, it works. And if I remove it, I am unable to hear any audio. Seems counter intuitive

Comment: And further that this is true in Chrome, but it works without adding the audio element in Safari

Comment: And Firefox just does not seem to work with either of the code

Comment: I suggest your create isolated test files that illustrate the misbehavior and then file bugs at the browser's bug tracker.

Comment: ok. will do. Thanks.

Comment: Did you succeed?